# Is there some way i can edit a Octave eps and send it to LaTeX to be edited with psfrag?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, psfrag, octave

I want to cut just a part of a eps plot made with Octave (its colorbar) and send it to LaTeX, still being able to use psfrag with it.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can include the whole thing an then use the options to includegraphics to clip to a specified rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the whole thing an then use the options to `\includegraphics` to `clip` to a specified rectangle